# Loading Bar - TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str

Tags: python

Example:

```
import time

# [...]

for x in range(3):
    x = "Loading" + "."
    print(x, end="\r")
    x += 1
    time.sleep(1.2)
```

I tried to make a loading bar and i got this error:

```
    x += 1
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str
```

I want this output:

```
>>>Loading.
>>>Loading..
>>>Loading...
```

What do I do?

Comment: Use `x += '.'`.

Comment: For progress bars, I find [tqdm](https://pypi.org/project/tqdm/) to be very helpful. It may be overkill for this specific case, but maybe you'd find a use for it another day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for x in range(3):
    x = "Loading" + "."
    print(x, end="\r")
    x += 1
```

You need to return to your tutorial materials and learn how to use your basic programming building blocks.  First of all, you have given the name `x` to two different programming ideas; this is the main source of your trouble.

- In the `for` statement, you say that you want `x` to be a counter from 0 through 2.
- In the final statement of the loop, you insist that you will control the value of `x` in a different way.
- In the other two statements, you say that you want `x` to be the string `Loading.`

You cannot have all of this at once.  Please see [How do Python variables work?](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html).

Instead,

1. get your concepts straight, and use a separate variable for each concept;
2. give each concept a meaningful name;
3. learn to trace your own work -- See this [lovely debugging site](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for help.

Here's a starting point:

```
bar = "Loading"
for count in range(3):
    bar += '.'       # Append one more dot to the bar
    print(bar, end='\r')
```

There is more work to do; I leave that up to you.

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by `x+=1`?
If you want to add `1` as a character do `x+=str(1)`
If you want to add a `dot` do `x+='.'`

Answer (score 1):

zazz and 9769953 already provided the fix, but you'll actually have to make some slight changes to your existing code to implement the fix correctly. Here's an example:

```py
import time

# [...]

x = "Loading"  # move outside the loop so we don't overwrite it
for _ in range(3):  # the loop variable isn't used, so use `_`
    x += "."  # append a dot to `x`
    print(x, end="\r")
    time.sleep(1.2)
```